# How to add iPhone version to iPad app which is alreadiy on the AppStore

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, ios-universal-app

Should I delete those iPad application in iTunes connect and submit a new one or there's a way to upload universal binary as next version?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the actual version to a universal version, and just submit this one as a normal update.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Of course I've prepared universal version, but in iTunesConnect I don't see a possibility to add iPhone screenshots in new version.

Answer (score 2):

Just upload a new binary with the correct version number. No need to delete anything in iTunes Connect. It will still have to get approved, so I suggest you update the app anyway you can if this is the only problem you have.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Of course I've prepared universal version, but in iTunesConnect I don't see a possibility to add iPhone screenshots in new version.

Answer (score 1):

Just scroll down, the iPhone option to load images is there, but you can't see the scroll bar.  That's one hour of my life I'm never gonna get back....